# What is best approach to set data to component from API in React JS

Tags: reactjs, components

We have product detail page which contains multiple component in single page.

Product Component looks like:

```
class Product  extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Searchbar/>
        <Gallery/>
        <Video/>
        <Details/>
        <Contact/>
        <SimilarProd/>
        <OtherProd/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Here we have 3 APIs for
- Details
- Similar Product
- Other Products

Now from `Detail` API we need to set data to these components

```
<Gallery/>
<Video/>
<Details/>
<Contact/>
```

In which component we need to make a call to API and how to set data to other components. Lets say we need to assign a,b,c,d value to each component

```
componentWillMount(props) {
  fetch('/deatail.json').then(response => {
      if (response.ok) {
        return response.json();
      } else {
        throw new Error('Something went wrong ...');
      }
    })
    .then(data => this.setState({ data, isLoading: false }))
    .catch(error => this.setState({ error, isLoading: false }));
}
```

OR

Do we need to create separate api for each components?

Answer (score 0):

Since it's three different components you need to make the call in the component where all the components meet. And pass down the state from the parent component to child components. If your app is dynamic then you should use "Redux" or "MobX" for state management. I personally advise you to use Redux

```
class ParentComponent extends React.PureComponent {

   constructor (props) {
     super(props);
     this.state = {
        gallery: '',
        similarPdts: '',
        otherPdts: ''
     }
   }


   componentWillMount () {
      //make api call and set data
   }

   render () {
      //render your all components
   }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Product` component is the best place to place your API call because it's the common ancestor for all the components that need that data.

I'd recommend that you move the actual call out of the component, and into a common place with all API calls.

Anyways, something like this is what you're looking for:

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import {
  SearchBar,
  Gallery,
  Video,
  Details,
  Contact,
  SimilarProd,
  OtherProd
} from "./components/components";

class Product extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    // Set default values for state
    this.state = {
      data: {
        a: 1,
        b: 2,
        c: 3,
        d: 4
      },
      error: null,
      isLoading: true
    };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.loadData();
  }

  loadData() {
    fetch('/detail.json')
      .then(response => {
        // if (response.ok) {
        //   return response.json();
        // } else {
        //   throw new Error('Something went wrong ...');
        // }
        return Promise.resolve({
          a: 5,
          b: 6,
          c: 7,
          d: 8
        });
      })
      .then(data => this.setState({ data, isLoading: false }))
      .catch(error => this.setState({ error, isLoading: false }));
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.error) return <h1>Error</h1>;
    if (this.state.isLoading) return <h1>Loading</h1>;

    const data = this.state.data;
    return (
      <div>
        <SearchBar/>
        <Gallery a={data.a} b={data.b} c={data.c} d={data.d} />
        <Video a={data.a} b={data.b} c={data.c} d={data.d} />
        <Details a={data.a} b={data.b} c={data.c} d={data.d} />
        <Contact a={data.a} b={data.b} c={data.c} d={data.d} />
        <SimilarProd/>
        <OtherProd/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<Product />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Working example here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/ymj07k6jrv

Answer (score 0):

You API calls will be in the product component. Catering your need to best practices, I want to make sure that you are using an implementation of FLUX architecture for data flow. If not do visit [phrontend](https://github.com/flipkart-incubator/phrontend)

You should send you API calls in componentWillMount() having your state a loading indicator that will render a loader till the data is not fetched.

Each of your Components should be watching the state for their respective data. Let say you have a state like {loading:true, galleryData:{}, details:{}, simProducts:{}, otherProducts:{}}. In render the similar products component should render if it finds the respective data in state. What you have to do is to just update the state whenever you receive the data.

Here is the working code snippet:

ProductComponent:

```
    import React from 'react';
    import SampleStore from '/storepath/SampleStore';
     
    export default class ParentComponent extends React.Component {
    
       constructor (props) {
         super(props);
         this.state = {
         loading:true,
         }
       }
    
    
      componentWillMount () {
        //Bind Store or network callback function
        this.handleResponse = this.handleResponse
        //API call here.
      }

      handleResponse(response){
      // check Response Validity and update state
      // if you have multiple APIs so you can have a API request identifier that will tell you which data to expect.
      if(response.err){
       //retry or show error message
      }else{
       this.state.loading = false;
       //set data here in state either for similar products or other products and just call setState(this.state)
       this.state.similarProducts = response.data.simProds;
       this.setState(this.state);
      }
     }
    
       render () {
          return(
           <div>
           {this.state.loading} ? <LoaderComponent/> : 
            <div>
             <Searchbar/>
             <Gallery/>
             <Video/>
             <Details/>
             <Contact/>
             {this.state.similarProducts && <SimilarProd data={this.state.similarProducts}/>}
             {this.state.otherProducts && <OtherProd data={this.state.otherProducts}/>}
         </div>
         </div>
         );
    
      }
    }
```

Just keep on setting the data in the state as soon as you are receiving it and render you components should be state aware.

Answer (score 0):

> In which component we need to make a call to API and how to set data
>   to other components.

The API call should be made in the Product component as explained in the other answers.Now for setting up data considering you need to make 3 API calls(Details, Similar Product, Other Products) what you can do is execute the below logic in `componentDidMount()` :

```
var apiRequest1 = fetch('/detail.json').then((response) => { 
        this.setState({detailData: response.json()})
        return response.json(); 
});
var apiRequest2 = fetch('/similarProduct.json').then((response) => { //The endpoint I am just faking it
    this.setState({similarProductData: response.json()}) 
    return response.json();
});
var apiRequest3 = fetch('/otherProduct.json').then((response) => { //Same here
    this.setState({otherProductData: response.json()}) 
    return response.json();
});

Promise.all([apiRequest1,apiRequest2, apiRequest3]).then((data) => {
    console.log(data) //It will be an array of response
    //You can set the state here too.    
});
```

Another shorter way will be:

```
const urls = ['details.json', 'similarProducts.json', 'otherProducts.json'];

// separate function to make code more clear
const grabContent = url => fetch(url).then(res => res.json())

Promise.all(urls.map(grabContent)).then((response) => {
    this.setState({detailData: response[0]})
    this.setState({similarProductData: response[1]})
    this.setState({otherProductData: response[2]})
});
```

And then in your `Product` render() funtion you can pass the API data as

```
class Product  extends Component {
    render() {
    return (
        <div>
        <Searchbar/>
        <Gallery/>
        <Video/>
        <Details details={this.state.detailData}/>
        <Contact/>
        <SimilarProd similar={this.state.similarProductData}/>
        <OtherProd other={this.state.otherProductData}/>
        </div>
    );
    }
}
```

And in the respective component you can access the data as :

```
this.props.details //Considering in details component.
```